# Trigger AWS Lambda function with a string payload

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a function on AWS Lambda written in Java that can currently only accept **text** event data, not **JSON**.

Whenever I go in the test console, if my test event has a payload of `"{}"`, the function runs, however if it's a json, `{}` it does not.

If I run it with any of the triggers, such as S3, CloudWatch Events or with a API Gateway, they always send out a json.

Is there by any chance a possibility to run those triggers and make them send a string payload instead of a json payload?

Answer (score 0):

To accept `JSON` as input, you need to update your `RequestHandler<JSONObject, String>` and

```
public class Hello implements RequestHandler<JSONObject, String>{
    public String myHandler(JSONObject jsonObj, Context context) {
       // add your processing logic.
       return "done!";
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can define a POJO with the attributes of your json payload like

```
class Payload {
  //fields
  //setter & getter
}
```

And use this Payload type in your RequestHandler as

```
public class Hello implements RequestHandler<Payload, String>{
    public String myHandler(Payload payload, Context context) {
       // add your processing logic.
       return "done!";
    }
}
```

Here `String` is your output data type. If its different in your case, you need to change that as well.

Comment: Refer this [lambda doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-using-predefined-interfaces.html) for detailed example.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however that was not the question. I am aware that that is the way to accept JSON payloads, I was asking how to configure lambda to sendout String payloads (like it does in the test console).

Comment: Referring to [CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html) and [S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html) these services will send out a serialized JSON object as payload. 
So you can update your lambda handler to accept JSON payload instead of String payload, if you feel its feasible.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have that option currently.

Comment: Okay. In case if you get to find some work around, please post it here.

Comment: @Zippie In the link to the lambda docs from snmaddula you can find another example which is taking an InputStream by using the RequestStreamHandler interface. From this stream, you can read the input into a String object by yourself. Does this help you?